# What is the equivalent of length in R to python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been using R to program and a naive in Python programming. I have a working code in R where I'm reading multiple files in a folder and sub-setting the file by few columns. The columns are not same in all the files.
So, in R, I wrote a code:

```
selectedcolumns <- df[,c(1,3:5,7:length(df))]
```

This code will select columns 1,3,4,5,7 and then will pick all the columns till the last column followed by 7th column present in the file.

In Python, while I'm trying a similar code, I'm unable to understand what could be the possible equivalent keyword for **"length"** that'll help me dynamically pick the last of the file from the desired column.

What I have been trying till now is:

```
import pandas as pd
selectedcolumns = pd.read_excel('ABC.xlsx',sheetname= "myfile", header = None, usecols = [1,3,4,5,7])
```

Now this code is reading the file and selecting the columns as mentioned. 1,3,4,5,7. However, I'm looking for 2 things over here:

1) Is there any better way to write **3:5** in Python as it's possible in R?

2) What can I write from 7th column till the last column since the last column is dynamic in all the files and I would require all columns from 7th in every file.

Any help will be useful since I'm new to Python.Not much aware of different functions or libraries for doing the same operation.

Comment: So somehow you lacked the tagging of pandas and possibly numpy (while using useless tags like subset and two python ones). Both their documentations will show you very easily how to do this.

Comment: A Stack Overflow question is for when your efforts to solve your problem on your own have proven fruitless. It shouldn't be where you *start* your research. These sorts of questions are well-covered in dozens of tutorials (which would explain such things as `len()`, `range()` and slices).

Comment: In any event, this might be helpful: http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-python-xref.pdf

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concatenating slices you can use numpy's r_ object. `np.r_[1:3, 6, 8:10]` returns `array([1, 2, 6, 8, 9])` for example. As for the length function, the equivalent is len. However, you'll need to call that on the `df.columns` collection (len(df) returns the number of rows).

`np.r_[1:3, 6, 8:len(df.columns)+1]` returns 1, 2, 6, 8, 9, ..., n where n is the number of columns.

Once you have the slices, you can use it inside `iloc` indexer:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:3, 6, 8:len(df.columns)+1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little bit complex after R, but if you want to copy all columns after selected up to the end you should use code like this:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,7:]
```

It will copy all columns from 7 to the last.

You can select multiple ranges this way:

`df1 = df[df.columns[0:1].tolist() + df.columns[7:].tolist()]`

Comment: @BradSolomon fixed